# Getting invalid credentials error while creating user in windows active directory from azure app service

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying below code to create new user in windows active directory. This code is working fine on local as well as when hosted on virtual machine. But same code is giving invalid credentials error when hosted on azure app service.

```
       using (
            var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain, DefaultContainerKey, UserName, UserPassword))
        {
            using (var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(pc))
            {
                userPrincipal.Surname = lastName;
                userPrincipal.GivenName = firstName;
                userPrincipal.EmailAddress = emailAddress;
                userPrincipal.SamAccountName = userLogonName;
                userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = string.Format("{0}@{1}", userLogonName, Domain);
                userPrincipal.DisplayName = $"{userPrincipal.GivenName} {userPrincipal.Surname}".Trim();
                userPrincipal.SetPassword(password);
                userPrincipal.Enabled = true;
                try
                {
                    userPrincipal.Save();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    _logger.Error("Exception creating user object. " + exception);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am able to create user from azure app service with below code. But It is again giving invalid credentials error when I try to connect to AD with user created using below code.

```
 LdapAttributeSet attributeSet = new LdapAttributeSet();
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("objectclass", new string[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user" }));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("samAccountName", userLogonName));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("cn", userLogonName));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("givenName", firstName));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("sn", lastName));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("mail", emailAddress));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("displayName", string.Format("{0}@{1}", userLogonName, Domain)));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("userPrincipalName", string.Format("{0}@{1}", userLogonName, Domain)));
                attributeSet.Add(new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", encodedPassword));

                string dn = $"CN={userLogonName},{defaultContainerKey}";
                LdapEntry newEntry = new LdapEntry(dn, attributeSet);
                LdapConnection conn = GetAdminConnection();
                conn.Add(newEntry);
                Console.WriteLine("Entry:" + dn + "  Added Successfully");
                conn.Disconnect();
                return true;
```

Can someone please help me to understand why this is happening.